# How to make a branch on top of a specific commit?

Tags: git

How will i create a new remote branch on top of a specific commit?

Here is how my current commits:-

> a-------b-------c--------d-------e

I checkedout new local branch from the point **'c' commit**

```
git checkout -b c-1 <sha>
```

I have made changes to 'c-1' branch. Now I want to create a remote branch that should look like this:-

```
a-------b-------c--------d-------e
                \
                 \
                  c-1 --------c-2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a branch that has two heads (`e` and `c-2`).  If you are asking how to push your local `c-1` branch to the `origin` repository under a different name:

```
git push -u origin c-1:newbranchname
```